# How to print an Instance?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to print an SMS, but i'm just printing "instance of..."

this is an app which show all sms in the smartphone on the display

i'm using the sms plugin

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {


  Future<List> getSMS() async {


  SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery();
  List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.getAllSms;



  return messages;
}

  @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
}




@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: getSMS(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
       switch(snapshot.connectionState){
        case ConnectionState.none:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:

        default:
            if(snapshot.hasError){
              return new Center(
                  child: Text("Erro ao Carregar Dados :(",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 25.0),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
              );
            } else {
            debugPrint(snapshot.data[0].toString());
          }
      }
        return new Center(
          child: Text(snapshot.data[0].toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 25.0),
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
          );
       },
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

all i need is to print the sms on display, but i don't know how to print an instance of object in dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only print Strings (since that's what the print console does). If a class doesn't have a `toString()` method built in, then you'll need to figure out where a string is. On that package it looks like `SmsMessage` has a `body` parameter which is a string. Since you have a list of SmsMessages you'll need to iterate through them in something like a forLoop and print their subsequent `body` parameters. To print the first message you can do `print(messages.first.body)`

Answer (score 4):

use `.toJson()` instead of `.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print in console all the messages:

```
print(snapshot.data.map((message) => message.body));
```

If you want to print in console the first message:

```
print(snapshot.data.first.body);
```

If you want to show in the `Text` widget all the messages:

```
Text('${snapshot.data.map((message) => message.body)}')
```

If you want to show in the `Text` widget the first message:

```
Text('${snapshot.data.first.body}')
```

If you want to display a list of `Text` widgets with all the messages:

```
Column(
  children: snapshot.data.map((message) => Text('${message.body}')).toList(),
)
```