# Flutter Getx Stream value changes to Instance after InIt

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I'm using Getx to bind a stream to userDataModel. On initialization, the value is printed from the firestore database, but later the values are null.

When are try to print the value by using `print(_userDataController.userDataModel.value.foodData);` It prompts null.

PS: In a previous project, I used the identical code. There, it still works.

The code is as follows

UserModel:

```
  Map? foodData;
  UserDataModel({this.foodData});

  factory UserDataModel.fromMap({dynamic dbData}) {
    return UserDataModel(
      foodData: dbData['foodData'],
    );
  }
}
```

Controller

```
class UserDataController extends GetxController {

// ================================= >  Stream READ
  /// Stream User Model
  Rx<UserDataModel> userDataModel = UserDataModel().obs;

  /// Stream
  Stream<UserDataModel> dbStream() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc('user1')
        .snapshots()
        .map(
      (ds) {
        var _mapData = ds.data();
        print(_mapData); // ONINIT THIS DATA IS PRINTING BUT LATER IT PROMPTS THE ABOVE ERROR

        UserDataModel extractedModel = UserDataModel.fromMap(dbData: _mapData);
        return extractedModel;
      },
    );
  }

  /// FN to bind stream to user model
  void bindStream() {
    userDataModel.bindStream(dbStream());
  }

// ================================= >  OnInIt
  @override
  void onInit() {
    bindStream();
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no error in your code. The message "Instance of" doesn't mean it is an error. This message always shows whenever your printing an object.

Comment: But oninit() it does prints the actual value instead of instance. Why? @emmy-chwan

Answer (score 1):

To know the content of the `Instance of '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, UserDataModel>'` try with `foodData.toString()`

You are getting this prompt because you are not converting the response into proper DataModel class.

You have to map the `json to DataModel` class.
For that you can just paste the response which is printed in the console to https://jsontodart.com/ this will prepare the data model class for you. Then you can access the elements by `iterating` through them and getting corresponding `instance variable`

For reference refer:

- [How to get data from Firebase Realtime Database into list in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61508047/13431819)
- [Flutter list return Instance of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59039488/13431819)
- [How to print an Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58492349/13431819)